# The best way to insert data to tSQLt faketable?

Tags: sql, tsqlt

I am quite new to tSQLt database unit testing framework.
I have a stored procedure that uses 3 tables. Each table needs 15 rows of data. I also need another fake table to validate the result.
But it’s error-prone and hard to maintain to use INSERT to prepare the fake tables.

What is the best practice to prepare data for tSQLt faketable?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your code and test? That will help us write an answer that is direct to your question. Until then, see my general guidance in the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

This is the best answer I can come up with without a code sample:

The idea of FakeTable is to make it simpler to insert test data into your tables during a test. It replaces the table with a copy that does not contain the constraints. This is so that you can place data only in the tables that are used by the stored procedure, function, view, etc that you are trying to test.

To that point, since FakeTable has removed the constraints, you are also free to only insert data into the columns of the tables you care about. That means that your insert statement can be shorter.

You say that each table requires 15 rows of data. When writing unit tests, I find it very rare that I need so much data to test a specific bit of the code. If I'm testing a stored procedure for example that contains a very complex select statement, I will write multiple tests for a variety of the conditions that can occur within that select statement. By doing this, when a test fails, I can more easily isolate where in the code the problem occurred.

You also say that you need a fake table to validate the result. I assume that you mean you need to insert the results of what you are testing into a table, or construct a table to hold the expected values. (Again, this is where posting an example would be very helpful). Here is an example of how I capture the results of a view and compare the expected and actual results. Notice that I don't use FakeTable for the Actual or Expected tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTests.[test CustomerOrderSummary counts orders for each customer]
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'Demo.Order';

  INSERT INTO Demo.Order (OrderId, CustId) VALUES (1, 12);
  INSERT INTO Demo.Order (OrderId, CustId) VALUES (2, 12);
  INSERT INTO Demo.Order (OrderId, CustId) VALUES (3, 12);
  INSERT INTO Demo.Order (OrderId, CustId) VALUES (4, 55);
  INSERT INTO Demo.Order (OrderId, CustId) VALUES (5, 55);

  SELECT CustId, NumOrders
    INTO MyTests.Actual
    FROM Reports.CustomerOrderSummary;

  SELECT TOP(0) *
    INTO MyTests.Expected
    FROM MyTests.Actual;

  INSERT INTO MyTests.Expected (CustId, NumOrders) 
      VALUES (12, 3);
  INSERT INTO MyTests.Expected (CustId, NumOrders) 
      VALUES (55, 2);

  EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'MyTests.Expected', 
                               'MyTests.Actual';
END;
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, any thoughts on how would you approach the INSERT INTO in a dynamic way? to avoid schema changes refactoring, we may have 10,000 tests, I'm guessing that using INFORMATION_SCHEMA and some sort of function to dynamically generate these values based on the data type?